Traveling to Europe with a US Refugee Travel Document
I would like to travel to Belgium. But appointment for visa application is limited. I saw online that Belgium is authorizing Visa-free entry to its territory for US lawful permanent resident who possesses a US Refugee Travel Document. Will the border let me into Belgium if I don’t have a visa ? Would I encountered difficulties at the border? Would I need to provide proof of income, lodging etc during my trip ?
Also, on my Travel Document it is saying that it’s a Permit of re-entry. My nationality is Vietnamese but I don’t have its passport. Will Belgium still let me in visa-free to its country?

Do you have a permanent residence, aka green card to US?

You can check the travel document requirements using IATA. If you have the right documents to be eligible to enter Belgium visa-free, at Belgian border control you may need to:show a return or onward ticket and that you have enough money for your stay (which AFAIK is a minimum daily amount of €45-€95 depending on your accommodation arrangements). You should also consider medical insurance needs.
